# Nginx fails to load static after putting caching configuration

Tags: caching, nginx

I am trying to implement leverage browser caching for my flask project nginx. But when i insert the code inside conf file static files are not served by nginx showing 403 permission denied error.

This is my conf file for site in site-enabled

```
server {

   listen  80;
   server_name site.in;
   root /root/site-demo/;
   access_log /var/log/site/access_log;
   error_log /var/log/site/error_log;

   location / {
      proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:4000/;
      proxy_redirect     http://127.0.0.1:4000 http://site.in;
      proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   }
   location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
      expires 30d;
      add_header Pragma public;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
   }
}
```

When i remove the cache expire part everything works fine. I tried similar question's answers and put root specification. But still error remains same. User specified in nginx.conf is www-data. Do i have to change user?

Comment: Why should nginx serve static files itself? It will forward everything to the proxy because of `location /`

Comment: So caching is not possible this way ?

Comment: It's possible, but you should understand what you do, not just put some random directives taken somewhere. In this case requests for static files doesn't proxied to `127.0.0.1:4000` anymore.

Comment: So how can i solve this ?